# UIView size not accepting size greater than 17000px

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uikit, uiscrollview

I want to use core text to draw string that can span over 100 pages. I'm trying to put a `UIView` in a `UIScrollView`. I'm overriding `drawRect:` to add text in this instance of `UIView`. The problem here is that I want to have only one `UIView` which is vertically scrollable and when I set the size of `UIView` to more than 17000 px, it doesn't show anything. So my question is how to write a huge amount of text using coretext in a single UIView so that it is vertically scrollable like UIVextView. Need help in this direction. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be better off by using multiple UIView's, also performance-wise. Try to create a subclass that creates another UIView for every x lines of text (e.g. 1 page), and let it draw just before it would enter the screen.

If this is not a possibility, why exactly would you need it to be in 1 UIView, and what do you need so much text in a scrollview for?

Comment: The Apple documentation says "In iOS 3.0 and later, views are no longer restricted to this maximum size but are still limited by the amount of memory they consume. It is in your best interests to keep view sizes as small as possible. Regardless of which version of iOS is running, **you should consider tiling any content that is significantly larger than the dimensions of the screen.**"